# JavaScript PopUp appears only ONCE on a page per user in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

This is something I already know the answer to but I want to come up with a better way.  I have a dropdown within a gridview.  Within the method that populates the dropdown data I'm adding an an "onchange" attribute to the dropdown.  The onchange calls a javascript function that is then used to fire a popup based on what the user selects on the dropdown.

My issues is I want the popup to display only once within that current page for that user.  The easiest answer is to use JavaScript sessionStorage to store some dummy value that is checked before the javascript popup code is run and then set afterwards.

The problem I'm having is that I then have to manage the storage by either clearing the storage when the user goes to another page by attaching storage.clear to all the buttons dealing with moving to another page.

Is there a way that I can clear the storage after the person moves to another page other than the page they are on.  BTW the dropdowns and javascript are all located within an ASP.NET custom control.  That custom control is loaded within several pages, therefore I want the logic to be isolated within the custom control so that I don't have to make changes to every page that uses the control and for modularity.

Answer (score 1):

You can in the page on load, just set a global js var to the page like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string script;
if (IsPostBack)
{
    script = "var isPostBack = true;";
}
else
{
    script = "var isPostBack = false;";
}
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "IsPostBack", script, true);
}
```

So, now in your js code, you can use isPostBack as a simple true/false var.